# Bash iteration from list of users

Tags: bash, sh

I would like to create a small bash script which let to list users on my FreeBSD servers. Then, it checks if `celery` user is in the list. If `"yes"`, do nothing, but if `"false"`, it creates the user `celery`.

This is my first draft:

```
alias list_users = 'cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd'
if "celery" in list_users:
    :
else:
    sudo adduser celery
```

Is it correct ? It's my first try with bash scripting.
It's maybe too pythonic !

This is the output:

```
alias: list_users: not found
alias: =: not found
alias: cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd: not found
```

Thank you very much !

Comment: You have too much whitespace: `alias list_users='cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd'`. But an alias is another name for the command itself, not the *results* of the command. You are also writing what looks like Python, not `bash`, in the following lines.

Comment: Thank you ! Exactly, it looks like Python as I said in my question. It was my way to define the issue. But thanks to @KamilCuk, I have a script which works.

Comment: Don't parse `/etc/password` use `getent`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash is all about external commands and regexes and substitutions and pipelines. Ex. checking if a user exists, is checking if every line in /etc/passwd starts with a proper string ending with `:`.

```
if ! grep -q '^celery:' /etc/passwd; then
    sudo adduser celery
fi
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be '^:celery:' with an extra : to ensure the correct user ID ?

Comment: Extra `:` in front of it? the format is `<user>:<encrypted password>:<user id>:...` see  [passwd(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/passwd.5.html). Matching `:` in front of the username is just invalid.